# carry out action every two posts except last post wordpress

Tags: count, slideshow, wordpress

I'm using the following to create a slide for a slideshow out of every two posts.

```
<?php $i = 0; $slideshow_query = new WP_Query("showposts=6&cat=10"); ?>
    <div id="slideshow-posts">
    <div class="newslide">
    <?php while ($slideshow_query->have_posts()) : $slideshow_query->the_post();      $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; $i++;  ?>
    //my content
    <?php if ($i == 2) { ?></div>  <div class="newslide"><?php $i = 0; } ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Problem is it creates a blank slide at the end - how would I get it to carry out creation of a news slide every two posts (or every even post) except for the last time an even post occurs?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator you're likely looking for is called **modulus** or modulo and returns your the remainder of a division:

```
$foo = 5 % 3;           //  5 = 1*3 + a remainder of 2
$bar = 17 % 5;          // 17 = 2*5 + a remainder of 2
$baz = 42 % 6;          // 42 = 7*6 + a remainder of 0
```

This operator comes in handy to identify even/odd rows in a loop when used with a divisor of 2:

```
0 % 2 => 0
1 % 2 => 1
2 % 2 => 0
3 % 2 => 1
4 % 2 => 0
…
```

Or in your case something like this:

```
<?php $i = 0; $slideshow_query = new WP_Query("showposts=6&cat=10"); ?>
<div id="slideshow-posts">
    <div class="newslide">
        <?php while ($slideshow_query->have_posts()) : $slideshow_query->the_post(); ?>   
            //my content
            <?php if ($i % 2 == 0): /* even: */ ?>
                </div><div class="newslide">
            <?php elseif ($i+1 == $slideshow_query->post_count): /* last: */ ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $i++; /* iterate in the end */ ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

In order to find out of you have reached the last post, you could compare `$i + 1` (since we start counting from 0) with the full amount of items returned by your query (max 6 in your example). And then close the `<div>` if they match.

**UPDATE**

I've extended the example above according to my comment. This isn't tested, but I believe that's how I remember it to work (the post count that is).

Comment: @polarbear - thanks - that didn't work for me though. I set `$i=+1` but couldn't figure out how to get rid of the last slide. I tried and `elseif ($i ==6): ?> </div> <?php endif; ?>` but that didn't work for me. In the end I've just done it maually  so just set it if conditionals for 2 4 and 6 posts, it would be better for something more flexible though I think.

Comment: `$i == 6` won't work, since in case of 6 posts, `$i` can never be more than 5, if you are starting to count from 0 on up. That's why you would compare e.g. `$i+1 == 6` or if you want to have it even more dynamic `$i+1 == $post_count`, where `$post_count` is the amount of post returned by your query. I believe it works something like `$slideshow_query->post_count`. I'll update my example.